# Catalan numbers - algebraic proof of the recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

> I would like to prove following recursive relation for the Catalan numbers:
>   $$\tag{1}
> C_0=1,\quad C_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}C_iC_{n-i-1}\text{, for }n\ge 1
> $$
>   **without combinatoric arguments, only algebraically; and no generating function.**

Starting point:
$$\tag{2}
C_n:=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}.
$$
The following recursion can be also used (already proved):
$$\tag{3}
C_0=1,\quad C_n=\frac{2(2n-1)}{n+1}C_{n-1}\text{, for }n\ge 1
$$
Maybe the identities [for Binomial coefficients (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) are useful. In particular the Chu–Vandermonde identity, 
$$\tag{4a}
\sum _{j=0}^{k}{\binom {m}{j}}{\binom {n-m}{k-j}}={\binom {n}{k}}
$$
or
$$\tag{4b}
\sum _{m=0}^{n}{\binom {m}{j}}{\binom {n-m}{k-j}}={\binom {n+1}{k+1}}
$$
could be useful.

What I have tried? I tried to substitute the definition (2) in the r.h.s. of (1) to obtain the l.h.s. of (1). Another attempt was to take $C_{n-1}$ from (1) (known by induction assumption) and try with (3) to recover $C_n$. In both cases, although I can smell that every thing is *more or less related* I can't find the technical steps to do the job.

A combinatoric proof with Dyck paths can be found [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/catalan-numbers/), but this is not the way I'm trying to follow.

**EDIT**
The answer by "Robert Z" is very good and nice and I'll accept it; if someone could find a direct proof without generalised binomial coefficient, I'will accept his answer instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First proof.**

Note that for $0\leq i\leq  n-1$,
$$C_iC_{n-i-1}=a(n,i+1)-a(n,i)$$
where 
$$a(n,j):=\frac{(2j-n)}{2n(n+1)}\binom{2j}{j}\binom{2(n-j)}{n-j}.$$
Hence, for $n\geq 1$,
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}C_iC_{n-i-1}&=
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(a(n,i+1)-a(n,i))\\&=a(n,n)-a(n,0)=C_n.
\end{align}$$

**Second proof.**

We have that
$$C_n=\frac{2(2n-1)\cdots (n+1)n}{(n+1)!}=2(-4)^n\binom{1/2}{n+1}$$
where we use the notion of [generalized binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series).

Hence, for $n\geq 1$,
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}C_iC_{n-i-1}&=4\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-4)^i\binom{1/2}{i+1}(-4)^{n-i-1}\binom{1/2}{n-i}\\
&=-(-4)^n\sum_{j=1}^{n}\binom{1/2}{j}\binom{1/2}{n+1-j}\\
&=-(-4)^n\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}\binom{1/2}{j}\binom{1/2}{n+1-j}+2(-4)^{n}\binom{1/2}{n+1}\\
&=0+C_n=C_n\end{align}$$
where we applied the [generalized Chu–Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity).

Comment: @Aaron Lenz I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: The central step here is $\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{1/2}{j} \binom{1/2}{n-j} = 0$. If you translate quantities of the form $\binom{1/2}{n}$ back into central binomial coefficients, then this becomes the identity $$ \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{1}{(2j-1)(2n-2j-1)} \binom{2j}{j} \binom{2n-2j}{n-j} = 0 $$ So if we want to make this proof meet the OP's request to avoid generalized binomial coefficients, then we probably need to find a proof for this identity about central binomial coefficients. (It is closely related to the Catalan recurrence relation, but looks slightly simpler and may be easier to prove.)

Comment: In case the identity above looks suspicious to you, note that for $j=0$ and $j=n$, the first factor is negative.

Comment: @sasquires I edited my answer. Please read my PS

Comment: @RobertZ Ah, beautiful!  I didn't see that.

Comment: @AaronLenz I think you should be able to rewrite this quite easily without any reference to $\binom{1/2}{n}$ or the generalized Chu-Vandermonde identity now. 
 It looks like you don't even need the ordinary Chu-Vandermonde identity.

Comment: @sasquires Yes, now the proof is quite short (some computations are omitted).

Comment: Thank you very much! Very very nice proof. You could also reinsert your old proof as second proof, it was very interesting and aesthetically better (IMO). But now I understand which direction my attempts had should take.

Comment: @AaronLenz Now you have two proofs! ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much, have a nice day!

Comment: @RobertZ Can you give me some kind of motivation on how to come up with the telescopic sum in your first proof? Thanks.

Comment: @Sarvagya In general use Gosper's algorithm. See https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf