# Finding general term for a given sequence

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, induction, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I am solving a combinatoric question in which I am getting this recurrence relation 
$$\color{red} {P(n) = 2P(n-1)+\sum_{k=3}^{n-2}P(k)P(n+1-k)}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \forall n>3$$
$$P(3)=1$$
It is to be shown that the general term is $$P(n)=\dfrac{\binom{2n-3}{n-1}}{2n-3}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall n\ge3$$
**My attempts:**

I tried induction but the sum is creating problem. Also, the sum suggests using generating functions (because it is like the coefficient of $x^{n+1}$ when multiplying two polynomials) but I failed here also.

Please help

**EDIT**

As suggested by S.Dolan in the answer, $P(n)=C_{n-2}$. The post on Wikipedia about Catalan number aptly explains the proof by generating functions. So the question now reduces to

> How to prove the formula for Catalan numbers by using induction? Catalan numbers are defined using $C_0=1 $ and $$C_{n+1}=\sum_{r=0}^nC_iC_{n-i}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are Catalan numbers, where your $P(n)$ is $C(n-2)$.

There are a number of proofs of the result you want given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number.

(Including one using generating functions, which is, as you so rightly say, is suggested by the form of the sum.)

Comment: Thank You for your help, S.Dolan. I understood the proof by generating functions. Can you please help me in the inductive step, if I try mathematical induction (Even in the original recursion for Catalan numbers will do $C_{n+1}=\sum_{r=0}^nC_rC_{n-r}$). There is no proof by induction given on wikipedia

Comment: I'll have a go now.

Comment: I've now had a go and cannot  see a  way of proving this directly by induction.You could try posting this again asking only for an inductive proof and you might also like to check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3304415

Comment: That answers it, thank you.